# Issue with nanospinner npm package

Tags: javascript, npm-package

When i try to use this package, according to documentation, i see only a dash instead of spinner:

[image]

The code is basically the same as it states in documentation:

```
  const spinner = createSpinner("Installing dependencies...");
  spinner.start();
```

Anyone faced similar problem before, and how to fix this?

Link to npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nanospinner

Comment: I found this info on ora npm package: On Windows, it will always use the line spinner as the Windows command-line doesn't have proper Unicode support. Probably this is the reasons why it's only a dash, because of windows cmd.